# Program Not Downloading 50 images using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os, bs4, sys, requests

try:
        os.mkdir('Downloaded_Images')
except FileExistsError:
        print('Saving files to Downloaded_Images folder')

for i in range(50):
        # What to search
        url_part_1 = "https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw$
        url_part_2 = "#imgrc=Ek3sgIvXh3zzZM%3A"
        image_to_search = sys.argv[1]
        search = url_part_1 + image_to_search + url_part_2

        # Issue GET request and download search page
        responce = requests.get(search)
        responce.raise_for_status()
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(responce.text, "html.parser")

        # Locate the images
        picture_element = soup.select('a img')
        if picture_element == []:
                print('Could not locate images something went wrong')
        else:
                picture_location = picture_element[i].get('src')
                print('Downloading ' + str(i))
                responce = requests.get(picture_location)
                responce.raise_for_status()
                image_file = open(os.path.join('Downloaded_Images', os.path.basename('image_' + str(i))$
                for chunk in responce.iter_content(100000):
                        image_file.write(chunk)
                image_file.close()
```

Here is my code I run it like so ./google_images_downloader.py what_you_wanna_search. However if you notice it says for i in range(50). Here is the problem it does not download 50 images only 19. It only downloads 19 no matter the search. What am I doing wrong? I get the error

picture_location = picture_element[i].get('src')
IndexError: list index out of range

But when I inspect element it looks like picture_element = soup.select('a img') is right. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your `url_part_1` definition is missing an end quote. Is this also an error in your program or just a typo here?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger? That is often a good place to start and would show you what the contents of the variables are at each step. It looks like at some point your picture_element list does not have 50 elements.

Comment: spruceb it is just a typo lol. pomtree; the thing is the are more than 50 images given from the google search? Is picture_element = soup.select('a img') not good enough, because  when inspecting element on images that It did not grab the area within <a> then img.

Comment: Ill try the debugger thank you

Comment: # Locate the images
        picture_element = soup.select('a img')
        if picture_element == []:
                print('Could not locate images something went wrong')
        else:
                try:
                        picture_location = picture_element[i].get('src')
                except IndexError:
                        print('Got an error')

Comment: Thats what I changed, but still not the answer I was looking for. Thanks for the tip. It helped get rid of the error.